# Java Reflection invoke nested method from static class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, mybatis

I am using myBatis and I need to call generated *andFieldEqualTo* method using Java Reflection.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.example.model.MyBatisExample");
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
Method method =  cls.getDeclaredMethod("createCriteria");
Method method2 = method.invoke(obj).getClass().getDeclaredMethod("andFieldEqualTo", String.class);
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.oneconnectft.sg.smartdocu.model.UserGroupExample$Criteria.andFieldEqualTo(java.lang.String)*

For Reference this is the MyBatisExample class

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyBatisExample {
    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This field corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    protected String orderByClause;

    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This field corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    protected boolean distinct;

    /**
     * This field was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This field corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    protected List<Criteria> oredCriteria;

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public MyBatisExample() {
        oredCriteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public void setOrderByClause(String orderByClause) {
        this.orderByClause = orderByClause;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public String getOrderByClause() {
        return orderByClause;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public void setDistinct(boolean distinct) {
        this.distinct = distinct;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public boolean isDistinct() {
        return distinct;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public List<Criteria> getOredCriteria() {
        return oredCriteria;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public void or(Criteria criteria) {
        oredCriteria.add(criteria);
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public Criteria or() {
        Criteria criteria = createCriteriaInternal();
        oredCriteria.add(criteria);
        return criteria;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public Criteria createCriteria() {
        Criteria criteria = createCriteriaInternal();
        if (oredCriteria.size() == 0) {
            oredCriteria.add(criteria);
        }
        return criteria;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    protected Criteria createCriteriaInternal() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        return criteria;
    }

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public void clear() {
        oredCriteria.clear();
        orderByClause = null;
        distinct = false;
    }

    /**
     * This class was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This class corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    protected abstract static class GeneratedCriteria {
        protected List<Criterion> criteria;

        protected GeneratedCriteria() {
            super();
            criteria = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
        }

        public boolean isValid() {
            return criteria.size() > 0;
        }

        public List<Criterion> getAllCriteria() {
            return criteria;
        }

        public List<Criterion> getCriteria() {
            return criteria;
        }

        protected void addCriterion(String condition) {
            if (condition == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Value for condition cannot be null");
            }
            criteria.add(new Criterion(condition));
        }

        protected void addCriterion(String condition, Object value, String property) {
            if (value == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Value for " + property + " cannot be null");
            }
            criteria.add(new Criterion(condition, value));
        }

        protected void addCriterion(String condition, Object value1, Object value2, String property) {
            if (value1 == null || value2 == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Between values for " + property + " cannot be null");
            }
            criteria.add(new Criterion(condition, value1, value2));
        }

        public Criteria andFieldIsNull() {
            addCriterion("field is null");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldIsNotNull() {
            addCriterion("field is not null");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldEqualTo(String value) {
            addCriterion("field =", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldNotEqualTo(String value) {
            addCriterion("field <>", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldGreaterThan(String value) {
            addCriterion("field >", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldGreaterThanOrEqualTo(String value) {
            addCriterion("field >=", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldLessThan(String value) {
            addCriterion("field <", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldLessThanOrEqualTo(String value) {
            addCriterion("field <=", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldLike(String value) {
            addCriterion("field like", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldNotLike(String value) {
            addCriterion("field not like", value, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldIn(List<String> values) {
            addCriterion("field in", values, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldNotIn(List<String> values) {
            addCriterion("field not in", values, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldBetween(String value1, String value2) {
            addCriterion("field between", value1, value2, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }

        public Criteria andFieldNotBetween(String value1, String value2) {
            addCriterion("field not between", value1, value2, "field");
            return (Criteria) this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This class corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated do_not_delete_during_merge Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public static class Criteria extends GeneratedCriteria {

        protected Criteria() {
            super();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This class corresponds to the database table smrtdocu.MY_BATIS
     *
     * @mbg.generated Fri Nov 08 16:30:42 CST 2019
     */
    public static class Criterion {
        private String condition;

        private Object value;

        private Object secondValue;

        private boolean noValue;

        private boolean singleValue;

        private boolean betweenValue;

        private boolean listValue;

        private String typeHandler;

        public String getCondition() {
            return condition;
        }

        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public Object getSecondValue() {
            return secondValue;
        }

        public boolean isNoValue() {
            return noValue;
        }

        public boolean isSingleValue() {
            return singleValue;
        }

        public boolean isBetweenValue() {
            return betweenValue;
        }

        public boolean isListValue() {
            return listValue;
        }

        public String getTypeHandler() {
            return typeHandler;
        }

        protected Criterion(String condition) {
            super();
            this.condition = condition;
            this.typeHandler = null;
            this.noValue = true;
        }

        protected Criterion(String condition, Object value, String typeHandler) {
            super();
            this.condition = condition;
            this.value = value;
            this.typeHandler = typeHandler;
            if (value instanceof List<?>) {
                this.listValue = true;
            } else {
                this.singleValue = true;
            }
        }

        protected Criterion(String condition, Object value) {
            this(condition, value, null);
        }

        protected Criterion(String condition, Object value, Object secondValue, String typeHandler) {
            super();
            this.condition = condition;
            this.value = value;
            this.secondValue = secondValue;
            this.typeHandler = typeHandler;
            this.betweenValue = true;
        }

        protected Criterion(String condition, Object value, Object secondValue) {
            this(condition, value, secondValue, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error when I ran the code :3

Comment: Use `getMethod`, not `getDeclaredMethod` - `getDeclaredMethod` only returns methods on the class itself, not from superclasses.

Comment: The problem was that I am running the reflection program in separate package and the methods I am calling were protected. I was able to resolve the issue by putting them on same package. Thanks for your help :)